# Showing a polynomial is greater than some number

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If we have a polynomial $p(x)\in \Bbb Z[x]$ of degree $n\geq 1$

If we let $a,b\in \Bbb Z$ with $b\gt0$.

> How do we show that $p(a/b)\ne 0\implies |p(a/b)|\geq b^{-n}$?

---

So we have, $a_n\ne0$,  $|p(a/b)| = |a_n\frac{a^n}{b^n} + a_{n-1}\frac{a^{n-1}}{b^{n-1}}+\cdots+a_1 \frac ab + a_0|\geq p(a/b) \ne0$

Is there a way to show perhaps that the minimal value that $p(x)$ attains is when $a=1,a_n=1$ and all $a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\cdots,a_0$ are zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$b^n|p(\tfrac ab)|=\left|a_na^n+a_{n-1}a^{n-1}b+\ldots+a_1ab^{n-1}+a_0b^n\right|$$ is a nonzero positive integer, hence $\ge 1$

Comment: I wish I could see these things like you mathematicians can, hopefully one day I will. Great work thank you